# Regex doesn't wok with persian characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this regex: `/می (\S+)/g` to get a word after `می`, it works on online test in `http://regex101.com/#javascript`, but it doesn't work when using it in the javascript itself.

I'm using the following code:

```
var optimized= $("#text").val().replace('/می (\S+)/g', 'می‌$1');
```

for example, this string:

```
من می توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی توانی همه را می کشی
```

should be replaced to this one:

```
من می‌توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی‌توانی همه را می‌کشی
```

it works on the online regex site, but not with my code... :(

Comment: nope, I'm trying to get two specified characters, not a whole range of Persian chars

Comment: Note that there is a U+200C after 'می' s in the example which prevents می and توانم to be like میتوانم and will be like می‌توانم.

Comment: see here for a live demo: http://narc.ir/mtp1376/bs/nimfaseler/index.html :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code, and it works;

```
var input = "من می توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی توانی همه را می کشی";
var optimized= input.replace(/می (\S+)/g, 'می‌$1');

console.log(optimized);
```

The only difference is the way to declare a regex.

You wrote:

```
.replace('/می (\S+)/g', 'می‌$1');
```

You need to either remove the slashes (and use the regex constructor), or the quotes

**Edit:** Running example with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/ghusse/LSpwU/

```
<textarea id="text">من می توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی توانی همه را می کشی</textarea>
<textarea id="optimized"></textarea>

<p><button id="go">Go</button></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var input = $("#text"),
    output = $("#optimized");

$("#go").click(function(){
    output.val(input.val().replace(/می (\S+)/g, 'می‌$1'));
});
```

Input:

> من می توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی توانی همه را می کشی

Output:

> من می‌توانم همه را بکشم، ولی تو نمی‌توانی همه را می‌کشی

Comment: O.o, when trying the code on chrome console and passing string directly to the js, it works! but doesn't work when using $("#text").val() and getting the text from a textarea :O

Comment: and still O.o, it works on jsfiddle, but I don't know why on my own host, it's doing wrong :O see here: http://narc.ir/mtp1376/bs/nimfaseler/index.html

Comment: Edit: it works, but needed to click the button two times to do O.o, Tnx :D

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the quotes (`'`) around your regex :

```
var optimized= $("#text").val().replace(/می (\S+)/g, 'می‌$1');
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4Fm6g/

Comment: still doesn't give the specific answer, I want to add a char code U+200C after 'می' on it, and still no chance :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're having problems because your Javascript file is being served with a different character encoding.

If your HTML is being served as `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, then your Javascript file should be encoded as `application/javascript; charset=UTF-8`. On an Apache server, you can serve all your Javascript files as UTF-8 by adding this line to your .htaccess file:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
```

Comment: I'm using .php file and js in inside it, I used .php for it, but no changes made... :D

Comment: In a PHP file, add `header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8);` before you output anything else. You may need to clear your browser cache to see the results.

Comment: I changed php file to html and added the line to .htaccess, but no change: http://narc.ir/mtp1376/bs/nimfaseler/index.html

Comment: You're doing something wrong. The [HTML](http://narc.ir/mtp1376/bs/nimfaseler/index.html) and [JS](http://narc.ir/mtp1376/bs/nimfaseler/a.js) files don't specify any character encoding at all.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to enable multi line flag on your regular expression, because it seems like you are going to run it against large pieces of text. here is how you do it:

`/می (\S+)/gi.test(X);`